# wso2 - get value from xml with property

Tags: xml, xpath, properties, wso2

I need to extract a value from an xml and store it in a property.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="myVersion2">1</localEntry>
```

I found something like that over internet:

```
     <property name="myProp"
               expression="get-property('registry','conf:repository/myVersion2.xml')"
               scope="default"
               type="OM"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="myVersion2.localEntry" expression="$ctx:myVersion2//localEntry"/>
     </log>
```

but doesn't works..

I have this error:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-03 16:27:43,495] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:    ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
```

What I need is to get the value between  and put it in a property..

Could someone please help me ?

Thank you

C

Comment: What I need is to read/extract the value '1' from that xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue!

it works!

```
        <property name="getSequence" expression="get-property('registry','conf:repository/myVersion2.xml')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="TestVersion" expression="$ctx:getSequence//localEntry"/>
    </log>
```

this is the output log:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-07 18:04:44,251]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  TestVersion = 1 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Thank you all for helping me!

Best Regards
Claudio

Answer (score 1):

Please change your configuration as follows.

```
  <log level="custom">
        <property name="myProp.localEntry" expression="$myProp//localEntry"/>
     </log>
```

Please try this out and let us know whether that solves your issue.

Comment: Hi Ravindra, I tried your suggestion but I got an exception: TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-06 14:09:43,631] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath} -  Evaluation of the XPath expression $myProp//localEntry resulted in an error {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath}
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: Variable myProp

Answer (score 1):

The above example is basically fetch the data from configuration registry if it is already there. But you asked, how to set the value in property. I hope the XML will already be in your message context....so just traverse through the xpath and set the value in a property mediator like below.

```
<property name="myProp"
           expression="\\some_element\....\localEntry"
           scope="default"
           type="String"/>
```

then u can easily refer this "myProp" to get the value from it using get-property() method.

Comment: the right sintax is expression="//localEntry" but in any case this doesn't works too

Comment: yes correct but ur xml does not meet the standard of SOAP message and wso2 only understand soap....so just ur xml in a form like below.                                                                                                            <soapEnvelope>

Comment: yes correct but ur xml does not meet the standard of SOAP message and wso2 only understand soap....so just ur xml in a form like below.                                                                                                            <?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="myVersion2">1</localEntry>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>